# J2ME: Discover only Computers during Bluetooth Discovery

Tags: bluetooth, java-me, iobluetooth

I am writing a security application for Laptops and I began writing the `DiscoveryListener` in J2ME
But it displays all device types like mobiles. But I want it to find only computers.

Any help regarding this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to search for a specific device type.
The search itself will always find all device types.

You will have to filter out unwanted devices yourself. When a device is found, `deviceDiscovered(RemoteDevice btDevice, DeviceClass cod)` is called. The `DeviceClass` tells you what kind of device it is. So simply ask.

```
if (cod.getMajorDeviceClass()==0x100) // Yes, it's a computer of some sort.
```

Comment: Um I tried it but with this enabled, my mobile is not finding any device including my laptop and when i remove this if loop it does.
So i got suspicious and i checked the actual value returned by the getMajorDeviceClass value and it was 256.

What does this number 256 mean??

Comment: Ignore my previous comment...I found a chart which has answered my question
http://www.jasonlam604.com/v2/index.php?action=tutorials&id=1001

Comment: If MajorDeviceClass 256 means a Computer then @mr_lou should change 0x0C for 0x100

Comment: Right you are. The 0x0c was actually for `getMinorDeviceClass()` telling us that the computer is a laptop.

Comment: Which is the majorDeviceClass int for detect phones?